# Sinatra-assetpack not merging js files

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, assets

I've been trying to compile the assets in a remote server with the `sinatra-assetpack` gem with not luck so far. It does compile when deploying it to Heroku or in my local machine but not in the remote server.

I have this configuration in my sinatra app file:

```
assets do
  serve '/js', :from => 'assets/javascripts'
  serve '/css', :from => 'assets/stylesheets'
  serve '/images', from: 'assets/images'
  serve '/bower_components', from: 'bower_components'

  js :landing, [
    '/bower_components/sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.min.js',
    '/js/back-to-top.js',
    '/js/subscription.js'
  ]

  js :checkout, [
    '/js/form.js',
    '/js/vendor/*.js'
  ]

  css :landing, [
    '/bower_components/sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.css',
    '/css/normalize.css',
    '/css/landing.css'
  ]

  css :checkout, [
    '/css/normalize.css',
    '/css/checkout.css',
    '/css/vendor/animate.css'
  ]

  js_compression :jsmin
  css_compression :sass
end
```

When I execute `rake assetpack:build`, all the files are correctly compiled except the `checkout.js`. It does indeed generate a `public/assets/javascripts/checkout.js` and its fingerprinted version but both of them contains just a `<h1> Internal Server Error </h1>`.

Removing the `form.js` (which is in reality a coffescript named `form.coffee`) from the precompilation process outputs a correctly compiled `checkout.js`. What is driving me nuts is that the `form.coffee` is correctly converted from coffee to javascript (I can see it at `public/js/form.js`) but it seems it cannot be merged with the vendor files.